# Android application for deleting data

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am new to android. I am building a small application to delete data. I want to delete a single data but it is deleting whole data. My code:

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

  public class DelbookActivity extends Activity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);

     Button btndel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btndel);
     btndel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     EditText value1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtISBN);

       public void onClick(View view) {
          final String PROVIDER_NAME="net.learn2develop.provider.Book";
          String val1=(value1.getText().toString());       
                getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://"+PROVIDER_NAME+"/books"),val1,null);

       }            
    });
 }
```

}

Any help greatly accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously its deleting the entire thing:

```
getContentResolver().delete(Uri.parse("content://"+PROVIDER_NAME+"/books"),val1,null);
```

This says delete the entire table named books. Try targeting a specific URI.